# how to substring character vector in R

Tags: r

I have a character vector in r as follows

```
"BEND"        "30⁰-4,9˚-1"
```

I want to substring only `degrees` from `"30⁰-4,9˚-1"` 
My desired vector would be

```
 "BEND"        "30,9"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "[A-Z]+|\\d+(?=°)"), paste, collapse=",")
@[1] "BEND" "30,9"
```

Or match the digits (`\\d+`) before the unicode symbol (`\\p{So}`)

```
sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "[A-Z]+|\\d+(?=\\p{So})"), paste, collapse=",")
#[1] "BEND" "30,9"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("BEND", "30°-4,9°-1")
```

Comment: @Neil  Could you check the stringr version?  I am using `stringr_1.2.0`

Comment: I think the degrees are not properly written, because I am reading the excel file.When I run your code on your sample data it runs fine.

Comment: @Neil Do you have severall types of degrees or just one type.  If it is one type, just copy paste that and use the first option

Comment: I have several types of degrees, some circles looks bigger some are smaller.

Comment: @Neil If you have `-` in all the cases, then try `sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "[A-Z]+|\\d+(?=.-)"), paste, collapse=",")`

Answer (score 1):

If the string in the example represents the pattern of all strings, you can use `gsub` in base R.

```
vec <- c("BEND", "30⁰-4,9˚-1")  # the data

gsub(".-[0-9]+", "", vec)
# [1] "BEND" "30,9"
```